# How to calclate users points

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got 5 equal tables which look like this:

**Table 1**

```
| Name  | Points |
|-------|--------|
| User1 |      5 |
| User1 |      2 |
| User1 |      5 |
| User2 |      1 |
| User2 |      7 |
| User2 |      9 |
```

The rows are inserted when a user answers different questions.
I also have the users in different table.

I want to:

```
echo User1: 12 points
echo USer2: 17 points
```

Ho can I make this?

Comment: this page may give you some more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_(SQL)#Queries

Comment: `I've got 5 equal tables `. what are other tables for??

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT name, SUM(points) as total_points FROM table1 GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm mistaken but I think this only sums data from one table while the OP said he had 5 of them. Maybe this is why it was downvoted. Apart from that, it's a pretty good answer.

Comment: @ConstantineLoukas - Yeah, makes sense, but what the heck does "5 equal tables" mean? He does not state what he wants with them and the example only sums the points from the one table. This is just a silly question, really.

Comment: I have two more identical tables like this one. Does anybody know how to gather the information and group by name from the 3 of them?

Comment: @OptimusCrime, he meant 5 tables with identical structure.